# Is it possible to have an internal link in a question/answer?

Tags: support, markdown, hyperlinks

Is it possible to have an internal link in a question/answer? I mean, the equivalent of

```
for a full explanation, please see <a href="#note1">note no. 1</a>.

 Bla bla bla
 ...

 ---
 <p id="note1">
 Very long explanation that would interfere with the exposition of the answer,
 ...
 </p>
```

Comment: "Anchor" would be the search term. Unfortunately, no, it's not possible. It was possible for a short time (staff had a feature turned on that inserted auto-generated anchors on headers in post bodies when rendering the Markdown), but it's no longer active, and it wasn't an officially-announced feature as far as I know, so there's not necessarily any reason to suspect that it'll come back. Lemme see if I can find a dupe...

Comment: No. ` id` isn't one of the supported HTML parameters (there's a list for that), and headers can't be used as an alternative over markdown parser reasons that aren't particularly important

Comment: On the global Meta, see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37894/support-anchor-names-in-posts; https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89314/automatically-add-id-attributes-to-headers-to-enable-link-targeting; and the ones they link/reference.

Comment: @CodyGray For the edit, for the useful comments, and for closing my question: thank you.

Comment: [HTML anchor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Anchor), *[fragment (identifier)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment)*. It isn't very distinct or search friendly (similar for "[HTML character entity references](https://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_latest.html#HTML_character_entity_reference)" (e.g. `&lt;`, `&amp;`, `&deg;`, `&ndash;`, `&mdash;`, etc.)). I call them "page anchors", but that is probably nonstandard.